# karma controller inject error

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to setup my karma tests but am having a problem getting my test to run.  I have my test written like this

```
describe("Test Controller", function() {
  beforeEach(module('thisApp'));
  var $controller;
  var x = 1;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  it('should work', function() {
    expect(x).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

but I'm getting an error

```
Test Controller should work FAILED 
.../node_modules/angular/angular.js:4631:53
forEach@/Users/.../node_modules/angular/angular.js:322:24
loadModules@/Users/.../node_modules/angular/angular.js:4591:12
createInjector@/Users/.../node_modules/angular/angular.js:4513:30
workFn@/Users/.../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3067:60
```

my conf file is including these files

```
files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/app.js',
      'app/controllers/*.js',
      'app/test/unit/*.spec.js'
    ],
```

If I remove the beforeEach(inject...) then my test will run and says success but it gives me that error when I include it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Controller injection code should be like this.

```
var controller;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('TestController', {
            $scope: scope
            //Inject more dependencies if you want to
        });
    }));
```